# I don't know why my json isn't generating as HTML

Tags: javascript, json, var

I think I have a syntax issue but I have no idea as far as why my image isn't showing up. Does anything look wrong in this to you.

```
var txt = {
    "characters": [
        {"thumbn":"<img src=\"http:\/\/galnova.com\/nu_images\/tiled.jpg\"\/>",},
    ]
};
```

**[Demo on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mn9LV/2/)**

### Full code:

**Markup:**

```
<div id="char">
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    Name: <span id="fname"></span></br>
    Species: <span id="spec"></span></br>
    Occupation: <span id="occu"></span></br>
    Cider: <span id="cid"></span></br>
    Description: <span id="desc"></span></br>
    Bio: <span id="bio"></span></br>
    Alliance: <span id="alli"></span><br>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function byId (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

var obj = {
    "characters": [
        {
            "thumbn":"<img src=\"http://galnova.com/nu_images/tiled.jpg\"/>"
            "fullName":"John Doe"
            "speci":"human male"
            "occup":"Web Personality"
            "cide":"Sleeper"
            "descr":"blah"
            "biog":"blarg"
            "allia":"chaos good"}
        {
            "fullName": "Jane Doe"
            "speci":"human female"
            "occup": "Movie Producer"
            "cide":"Citric"
            "descr":"bluh"
            "biog":"blurg"
            "allia":"neutral"}
        {
            "fullName": "Canter Doma"
            "speci":"alienmale"
            "occup": "Chef"
            "cide":"Galv"
            "descr":"bleh"
            "biog":"blerg"
            "allia":"evil"
        }
    ]
};

//var obj = txt;
byId("thumb").innerHTML = obj.characters[0].thumbn;
byId("fname").innerHTML = obj.characters[0].fullName;
byId("spec").innerHTML = obj.characters[0].speci;
byId("occu").innerHTML = obj.characters[0].occup;
byId("cid").innerHTML = obj.characters[0].cide;
byId("desc").innerHTML = obj.characters[0].descr;
byId("bio").innerHTML = obj.characters[0].biog;
byId("alli").innerHTML = obj.characters[0].allia;
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to generate as HTML?  What is the code that should be doing that?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking. JSON is never HTML, although it can contain HTML. Please invest more time into articulating what exactly it is you want to know.

Comment: Check my answer again

Comment: If you appreciate an answer, don't forget to "accept" the best one by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer, underneath the voting arrows. This will also award you some reputation points! If a better answer comes along later, you can switch to that one. If you haven't taken the SO tour, check it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

### Update based on comments:

The issue is that you are using `document.getElementById`, but the element in question has a class, not id. Simply change `<div class="thumb">` to `<div id="thumb">`.

I'll update your question to include the relevant code and link to jsfiddle.

### Old Answer (has some helpful notes)

While your JSON has errors, they do not stop the html from being valid. I tested it by adding the image to the page with: `document.body.innerHTML = txt.characters[0].thumbn;`

Regarding your json, you have unnecessary commas and escaping in the html itself. This is cleaner:

```
var txt = {
  "characters": [
    {"thumbn":"<img src=\"http://galnova.com/nu_images/tiled.jpg\"/>"}
  ]
};
```

[**Live demo here (click).**](http://jsbin.com/OgaLeCAy/2/edit)

I think the better practice would be to simply store the img url (src) in the json, and generate the html for it like this:

```
var txt = {
  "characters": [
    {"thumbn":"http://galnova.com/nu_images/tiled.jpg"}
  ]
};

var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = txt.characters[0].thumbn;
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/OgaLeCAy/3/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt = {
    "characters": [
        {"thumbn":"<img src=\"http:\/\/galnova.com\/nu_images\/tiled.jpg\"\/>"}
    ]
};
```

And here is your working scripts: http://jsfiddle.net/mn9LV/3/

You had an error: `<div class="thumb">` instead of `<div id="thumb">`

Comment: @user3174713 you should have included this link in the post itself.

Comment: Just as my answer says: You had an error: `<div class="thumb">` instead of `<div id="thumb">`, so I changed the `class` to `id`

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be extra comma after ../tiled.jpg\"/>"

```
var txt = {
    "characters": [
        {"thumbn":"<img src=\"http:\/\/galnova.com\/nu_images\/tiled.jpg\"\/>"},
    ]
};
```

Comment: After closing `}` either

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mn9LV/4/ I took all the commas out and now Im getting an error at line 9 and I dont know why. Everything looks the same but its still not generating

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate you taking the time to help me

Comment: Any idea how I can generate every object on the page at once?

Comment: I just broke it. Please help. I was trying to make all the IDs Classes so that the generated html wouldnt break when I tried to put more than one on the page and now it broke. What did I do wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/mn9LV/5/